# Cannot debug outlook 2007 project on outlook 2007?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, vsto, outlook-2007

I'm getting the error 'You cannot debug or run this project, because the required version of Microsoft Office application is not installed'

The project was created as an Outlook 2007 add-in and Outlook 2007 is definitely installed. I can even manually deploy it by running the VSTO file after building the project, but still get that message when attempting to debug.

is there a value I have to change somewhere to make it work again?

Answer (score 0):

Have you check the condition in your project build rules that triggered this error? (which line in .vcproj file?)

If it's not a new project, you could try to create a new one, check whether it works and compare your project with the new one for differences (.vcproj file)